# Change console title if it is opened from other process in .NET Core C#

Tags: c#

I open a new dotnet process which points to a dll.

For example, I have app called A and B.

The A launch a new process of B with `Process.Start(...)`

```
ProcessStartInfo pi = new ProcessStartInfo();
pi.UseShellExecute = false;
pi.CreateNoWindow = true;
pi.FileName = "dotnet";
pi.Arguments = "pathTo.dll";
```

and in B which is a dotnet core console

```
static Main(string[] args) 
{
    Console.Title = "Custom title";
}
```

The problem is that in Task Manager, I see like `.NET Host` instead of `Custom title`:

[image]

How to solve it ?